# How to update platform version in AWS ElasticBeanStalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have a production ElasticBeanStalk on N.Virginia region. This environment uses a deprecated platform branch. Amazon recommended that we upgrade to a supported platform branch.

**Platform branch - Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux**

**Current Platform version - 4.10.2**

**Current node js version - 10.16.3**

**Recommended Platform version - 4.17.9**

[image]

I just tried to upgrade to a supported platform branch for Elastic Beanstalk. When I try to change the version in Platform, Amazon recommend us to clone the current environment, which creates a newer version of the platform, and then swap the CNAME of the environments.

[image]

After I cloned my environment, its Health status like "**No Data**".

[image]

When I try to change the Platform version in cloned environment, it doesn't allow me to update due to Health status is Invalid state.

[image]

Can any one please advice on this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs  4.17.9 is [only available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platforms-supported.html#platforms-supported.nodejs) for  `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v5.4.4 running Node.js 14` EB platform version. This EB is based on Amazon Linux 2 (AL2). Your current version uses AL1. They are incompatible with each other.

This means you have to **manually migrate** your current EB application to new environment based on AL2. The general steps for this are described in AWS docs:

- [Migrating your Elastic Beanstalk Linux application to Amazon Linux 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.migration-al.html)

Comment: Many thanks Marcin, I will check and update here.

Comment: @LakshminarayananS How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: I'm doing manually migrate (build new environment with supported platform). I hope it resolve my issues.

Comment: Hi marcin, I have completed this setup. But its showing one issue " Error: Restart Target Failure: restarting target eb-app failed: 
Command /bin/sh -c systemctl restart eb-app.target failed with error exit status 5. Stderr:Failed to restart eb-app.target: Unit not found.
"

Comment: Firstly issues raised for changing node versions in package.json. After i updated and restarted the app-server in EBS console. Now its showing issues Error: Restart Target Failure: restarting target eb-app failed:

Comment: An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [check Procfile]. Stop running the command. Error: node.js may have issues starting.

Answer (score 0):

EBS comes under "managed services", meaning, AWS should internally manage the instances. AWS should automatically migrate when the environments become obsolete. Yet, AWS is not doing so.

There might be some technical challenge in doing so, that is why I see the "Change" button being disabled. I migrated manually to newer instance. Exploring ways to mitigate this issue in production. Manual migration is going to be a costly affair.

Will keep this post updated post my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky way to do this.

1. Install EB cli https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html
2. Once it's properly configured and you have selected the correct application and environment, run `eb config`
3. It'll open an editor showing you the configuration for your environment, like this: [image]
4. **Carefully** edit the PlatformArn with the version that you want (you can get the available versions by pretending to create a new environment in Beanstalk).
5. Save and exit the file. This will trigger an environment update.
6. Terminate your existing instances to force Beanstalk to get new ones.

Once it's done, it'll show the new version in Beanstalk.